# Whether it is possible insert in Kingston SNA-DC/U hdd drive, but not ssd?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I have Kingston SNA-DC/U enclosure, it came bundled with ssd kingston drive.
Whether it is possible insert in this SNA-DC/U enclosure hdd drive, but not ssd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably yes. Its the same standard interface, and those enclosures are typically standard. You might have a bit of trouble fitting in a 9mm 2.5 inch drive, but there's no reason you can't stick a regular 7mm/2.5 inch HDD in there.